# XPath/PHP: Fix a query on a DOMNode

Tags: php, xpath

I'm testing a method that produces HTML representations of PHP values. The test method looks like this:

```
public function testIndexedArray()
{
    $array = array('alpha','beta','gamma');
    $element_dom =  method_that_turns_array_into_DOMDocument();
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($element_dom);

    $this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("/div/em[text()='array']")->length);
    $this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("/div/ul")->length);
    $this->assertEquals(count($array), $xpath->query("/div/ul/li")->length);
    $nodes = $xpath->query("/div/ul/li");
    foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
        $node = $nodes->item($index);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("/li/strong[text()='$index']", $node)->length);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("/li/em[text()='string']", $node)->length);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("/li/span[text()=concat(\"'\",'$value',\"'\")]", $node)->length);
    }
}
```

The HTML that `$element_dom->saveHTML()` produces is this (formatted for readibility):

```
<div>
  <em>array</em>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>0</strong> <em>string</em> <span>'alpha'</span></li>
    <li><strong>1</strong> <em>string</em> <span>'beta'</span></li>
    <li><strong>2</strong> <em>string</em> <span>'gamma'</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the HTML that I am expecting. But my test fails at the first assert in the `foreach($array)` loop. I'm having the hardest time tweaking the queries to make this test pass. How do I fix these queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues with your queries inside the loop:

1. Your context node is `li`, so you shouldn't start query with it
2. When you make query from a context node you should omit `/` at beginning ([check an example from manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php#example-6343))

Lines with fixed queries (checked with PHP 7.2):

```
$this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("strong[text()='$index']", $node)->length);
$this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("em[text()='string']", $node)->length);
$this->assertEquals(1, $xpath->query("span[text()=concat(\"'\",'$value',\"'\")]", $node)->length);
```